# WordPress - WP_Query - Difference of two meta values

Tags: php, wordpress

**Question:** Can I sort posts after doing some mathematics on meta value numbers?

**Explanation:** Lets say I have two meta keys.

required
current

How/If can I use WP Query, orderby meta_value_num and meta_query do sorting of posts based on the difference of required and current?

Something like,

```
    $sortbyArgs = array(
        'post_type' => 'myproduct',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_query' => array(      
                            'relation' => 'required - current',             
                            array('key' => 'required'),
                            array('key' => 'current'),

                        )
    );
```

So I might get posts sorted by remaining ( remaining = required - current )

Comment: Doubt you can do that. You'll probably need SQL query. From [meta query page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query): `You can optionally pass the relation key and set it to either OR or AND. It defines the relation, when there is more than one meta query (whether all of the conditions should be met, or at least one of them needs to be met).`

Comment: @dingo_d, thank you for taking interest. Is there a workaround to get the job done? using WP_Query isn't essential.

Comment: As I've said, you'd need to use SQL. Something that has this: `global $wpdb; $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'myproduct' AND post_status = 'publish' ...", OBJECT );`. Now you'll probably need to connect the second query in the post_meta table and use it to order the posts in the first select. [Read more](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)